# Ubuntu 12.04 Nvidia driver updates includes AMD drivers

Tags: drivers, 12.04, nvidia, update-manager, amd-graphics

Why is there **AMD** drivers included in **Update Manager** in Ubuntu 12.04.

Should I install them?
And why would Ubuntu allows you to install them?

I've already installed the Nvidia drivers except these AMD drivers.
[image: Update Manager]

Answer (score 0):

If you have an nvidia card in your computer, you don't need this packages. You could either remove them from your system or update the packages, as you like.

Comment: i think i accidentally installed some **amd** config files in my ubuntu 12.04. Is it safe to delete them.

Comment: how would i uninstall all amd drivers?